# Readable alternative to nib files?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nib

To me, the basic problem with nib files is that they are not human readable, so it's difficult to impossible to tell if there are unintentional or undesirable changes in the file, such as accidentally dragging a view.

Are there any nib alternatives out there that address this?

Comment: Sometimes I wish downvotes required an explanation. Was I not clear about something?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably not, because nib file represent a correct complex setup of your UI.
That can never be human readable like prose.

An alternative would be to programmatically create your ViewController.
This then is as human readable as you can implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by "prosa"?